# Multiple unique constraints on different columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

There is a crucial table in my `Oracle 11g` database. It has an `index column` which is set as `primary key`. There is a second column that holds strings that must be unique. I have added a `unique constraint` for that one. Now there is a third column that should also have a unique constraint.

When I use the `ALTER TABLE` statement I get the error

> 'ORA-02299: duplicate keys found' error.

I know that it is possible to create a unique constraint over several columns but this is NOT what I want. I need the columns to be independently unique:

```
    ALTER TABLE someTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint1_someTable UNIQUE (column2);
    ALTER TABLE someTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint2_someTable UNIQUE (column3);
```

I expect all the entries in all the columns of this table to be completely unique. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: "I expect all the entries in all the columns of this table to be completely unique" - but have you checked that is actually the case for the existing data? The error suggests it is not true, so you'll need to figure out how to resolve the duplicates, unless you only want to enforce uniqueness for new entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your column contain some duplicate keys, so you get the error when you try to apply a unique index.
Check that you don't have any duplicate values before setting the Unique Constraint.

Answer (score 3):

you have to find and eliminate the duplicate values of the column, before you can add an unique constraint on it.

You can use the following query to find the duplicate values

```
select column3 from someTable group by column3 having count(*) > 1;
```

If you cannot eliminate the duplicate values but want to prevent the new duplicates, you can add the unique constraint with the `NOVALIDATE` option using a **non-unique** index.

```
ALTER TABLE someTable
 ADD CONSTRAINT constraint2_someTable UNIQUE (column3) 
   USING INDEX(CREATE INDEX column3_ix ON someTable (column3)) ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

schurik's solution should work. 
Another solution is self join.

```
select t1.column1, t1.column3, t2.column3
from someTable t1, someTable t2
where t1.column1 = t2.column1
and t1.column3 = t2.column3
and t1.rowid <> t2.rowid
```